# Determine if point is within the bounds of 3 lines

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is a diagram of what I'm asking:
[image: Diagram]

I have the values of p1 through p7. Using these points, how can we determine if p7 is within the bounds of those 3 lines (as pictured in the diagram -- given left or right of the center line on p5 (line 1).

Taking into account possible rotation of the whole thing.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

EDIT:
The formula needs to be able to handle rotation like these 2 scenarios. NOTE that there needs to be an option to either select the left or right or up or down groups. In the original diagram, the right group is selected. In Scenario 2, the down group is selected. In Scenario 3, the up group is selected.
[image: Scenario 2]
[image: Scenario 3]

Comment: Why don't you represent these lines as equations?

Comment: I could... Given 3 line equations, how could I determine if p7 is within those bounds?

Comment: I'm not very good at math...so pardon my not-so-good explaining.

Comment: OK. I have a question. The line $2$ and $3$ is parallel to $x$-axis? Also, the line $1$ is parallel to $y$-axis?

Comment: Not necessarily. Like I said, this could all rotate.

Comment: But line 2 and 3 are always parallel. and line 1 is perpendicular to line 2 and 3.

Comment: What is the definition of the 'true' region? When I have three random lines, what would be the good region?

Comment: The true region is that highlighted area to the right of line 1 and between line 2 and 3.

Comment: Are the two horizontal lines always parallel? In that case, the 'true' region would thus be between the two parallel lines and on the same side of $P_5P_6$ as $P_2$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So if we write the equations corresponding to these lines, $y = a_i x + b_i$ where i=1,2,3 for each of the lines, then the condition for point 7 to be between lines 2 and 3 is $[y_7 - (a_2*x_7 + b_2)]*[y_7 - (a_3*x_7 + b_3)]<0$. The condition for $P_7$ and $P_2$ to be on the same side of line 1 is $[y_7 - (a_1*x_7 + b_1)]*[[y_2 - (a_1*x_2 + b_1)]>0$.

Comment: A line perpendicular to two parallel lines divides the region enclosed in to two; which of these are you considering as the region of interest?

Comment: Hey Ari, it depends on the situation. I'd like the option to set either "left" or "right". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 : $$L_1 : x=a,\ L_2 : y=b,\ L_3 : y=c$$ where $b\gt c$.

Now, the point $P_7(p,q)$ is in your bounds if and only if
$$p\ge a, c\le q\le b.$$

Case 2 : $$L_1 : y=ax+b,\ L_2 : y=-\frac{1}{a}x+c,\ L_3 : y=-\frac 1ax+d$$ where $a\gt0,$$c\gt d.$

Now, the point $P_7(p,q)$ is in your bounds if and only if
$$q\le ap+b, q\le -\frac{p}{a}+c, q\ge -\frac pa+d.$$

Case 3 : $$L_1 : y=ax+b,\ L_2 : y=-\frac{x}{a}+c,\ L_3 : y=-\frac xa+d$$ where $a\lt0,$$c\gt d.$

Now, the point $P_7(p,q)$ is in your bounds if and only if
$$q\ge ap+b, q\le -\frac{p}{a}+c, q\ge -\frac pa+d.$$

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. This is extremely helpful!!!

Comment: You are welcome! Have a nice day!

Comment: Quick question. With regards to the cases you presented. Should I just stick with one? Or should I mix and match depending on how the lines are rotated?

Comment: If you are given there points, you can know the representation of the lines. Then, you'll know which case you are in.

Comment: If I were to use case 1, I would have to switch X and Y depending on the rotation, correct?

Comment: For example, if I were to rotate the entire drawing 90 degrees, then case 1 would be L1:y=a, L2:x=b, L3:x=c ?

Comment: You mean you are given these points and then rotate the entire drawing?

Comment: Well, the points I'm given could correspond to a similar drawing rotated 90 degrees. They don't necessarily lock to the X and Y axis like my drawing suggests. Do the other cases hold up well to rotation?

Comment: What do you mean 'correspond to'? I thought your points are already rotated 90 degrees, so we have the fixed points.

Comment: Oh, nope. Not fixed points. The points could be anything. What I mean is that the whole entire drawing (p1-p7) are not fixed. It could be rotated depending on the scenario. So the formula needs to be able to handle any rotation of those points.

Comment: OK, but at some time, you know where the points are, don't you? That means at the time, you can get the coordinate of the points.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: But how do I take into account the rotation? Because X will be Y and Y will be X?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know your scenario. So, hard to explain.

Comment: Added more examples to the question that should clarify what I'm asking... Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12213/discussion-between-objectiveccoder001-and-mathlove)